# How to save files with incremented name

Tags: android

```
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Myfolder/"+"/Recording.mp3";
```

I have been buiding this application for recording audio, and I wanted to have my recordings an unique name with an increment eg. Recording 01.mp3, Recording 02.mp3 etc.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `SharedPreferences` to store the increment number:
First declare `SharedPreferences` as below:

`SharedPreferences prefs = getActivty().getSharedPreferences("fileNumber",MODE.PRIVATE);`

Then in your code you can:

```
int i = prefs.getInt('Number',1); 
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Myfolder/"+"/Recording" + Integer.toString(i) +".mp3";
i++;
```

And then save the incremented Number:

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("Number",i);
    editor.apply();
```

Comment: I used it but then, it was overwriting files with only only one name. The iteration did'nt work. So kindly can you tell where should I put the i++ part?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the number in SharedPreferences and add that to the filename, here an example of SharedPreferences

[SharedPref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example/)

Answer (score 1):

You Can Store With Append Device Time With File Name this code will Working fine for your requirement

Please Put This code

```
outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Myfolder/"+"/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"Recording.mp3";
```

Comment: I already used this but it confused users a lot. Thanks for stopping by though

Comment: This is Same problem in sharedPreferences

Comment: you can store number on sharedpreferences and you store multiple file sharedpreferences is not work when lots of file.

Comment: please i can suggest you use device miliseconds time to better implementation